# Создание и проверка на существование файла в несколько раз в функции

Tags: php

Каждый раз при выполнении скрипта создается определенный файл с помощью готовой функции.Но когда при выполнении в связи с особенностями *функций php* приходится проверять существует ли файл несколько раз,возникает трабл.Само название файла вытекает из

> date(); - в итоге название 2015-etc.txt

Появляется вопрос как записать спец.метку чтобы при обращении к функции повторно файл не создавался при осуществлении проверки.Возможно необходимо записать в **GLOBALS**,но и тут беда.

Код:

```
// Предупреждаю - это слабый пример для понятия.Он вообще не рабочий
function InTxt($str){
if(!$metka){
  $metka = date(Y);
 }
$han = fopen("$metka.txt", 'a+');
fwrite($han, $str);
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, а то ничего не понятно.

Comment: "возникает трабл" - непонятно, что за особенности и что за трабл. Если нужно проверить наличие файла, то вам нужна функция `file_exists()`.

Comment: @Etki в файл будут еще записываться данные + это можно использовать только как проверку.Но не забывайте что необходимо обращаться несколько раз и каждый проверять есть ли такой.Если нету создаем с текущей датой

Comment: Я не могу ничего забыть - я вообще не понимаю, с какой задачей вы боретесь

Comment: @Etki Теперь пишу коротко и ясно...Первый раз когда идет обращение к функции должен по сути создаваться файл.Второй раз проверяется создавался ли какой-то файл.Не важно каким образом это проверяется.И как второй, так работает третий - десятый раз.Как это можно записать нормально чтобы минимум и работало корректно

Comment: Как я и написал - проверяйте с помощью `file_exists()`, существует ли уже такой файл.

Comment: @Etki А как метку сделать?Поймите,у меня название берется с помощью date() и нужно как-то же это название запомнить

Comment: Я ей-богу не понимаю суть задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил использованием глобалс (тоесть создал метку где сохранилось название) и проверки с помощью if.